# Meaning of error converting brace enclosed initializer list to type?

Tags: c++, initialization

I'm trying to port/build g++ to run on my system, and running into the following error while building libstdc++:

> .../gcc-4.6.2/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/mutex:226:50: error: could not convert '{0}' from '`<brace-enclosed initializer list>`' to '`std::timed_mutex::__native_type {aka pthread_mutex_t}`'

The relevant code in `include/mutex` is:

```
class timed_mutex
{
    // ...
    __native_type  _M_mutex;
    // ...
    timed_mutex() : _M_mutex(__GTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT) { }  // Line 226
    // ...
}
```

`__native_type` is `pthread_mutex_t` and `__GTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT` expands to `{0}`.

I'm not very familiar at all with C++, just C, but I can't see anything obviously wrong here. What does the error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
timed_mutex() : _M_mutex({__GTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT}) { }  // i.e. _M_mutex({{0}})
```

However that feature is available only with **C++11**. [Demo](http://ideone.com/ZS1Dr).
For older compilers, you **can't use initializer list** with constructor.

The reason for having 2 `{}` is that, `pthread_mutex_t` is a `union` defined as [shown here](http://ideone.com/nSSRM). Which contains, a `struct`, `char[24]`, `long int`; thus naturally the initialization syntax would differ.

Update:
When I tried to compile `<mutex>` header in a test file, it gives following error:

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
>   file requires compiler and library support for the **upcoming ISO C++**
>   standard, C++0x. *This support is currently experimental, and must be
>   enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x* compiler options.

Quite possibly the particular file follows the *initializer syntax* of C++11.

Comment: This code is part of libstdc++, not code I wrote. Actually I just got it to work by changing the definition from `{0}` to `{{{0}}}`, but I'm a bit confused why the number of brace levels matters. Is this an area where C++ differs from C?

Comment: @R.., I have updated the answer. Note that, `pthread_mutex_t` is a `union` with 3 elements in it. May be your compiler is older or doesn't support some g++ extensions.

Comment: You're assuming a particular implementation of `pthread_mutex_t`; I'm porting to a system with a different one.

Comment: Anyway +1 and accepted. Perhaps due to lack of clarity about what I'm doing your answer made a few wrong assumptions, but it got me on the right track to solving the problem. I'd still be interested in knowing if/why C++ really requires matching brace levels for initializers (whereas C does not).

Comment: @R.., see an update in my answer. You are trying to build `<mutex>` library which is of new standard C++11. To support that you need to have C++11 compiler/support.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build `libstdc++` as part of the GCC/G++ build process. It's the version matching the compiler (GCC 4.6.2) so C++11 support is not an issue. The issue is that it did not like my system's definition of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.

Comment: @R.., g++4.6* does support some features of C++11. However, remember that you have to give flag like `g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp`. C++11 is not yet the default standard for gcc. gcc still follows C++03 unless you inform it explicitly.

Comment: That's all fine but it's not relevant to the question. g++ is perfectly happy to compile *its own source* provided it's happy with the host system. The problem was that the definition of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` was not C++-compatible.